# Value matching in SAS IML

Tags: sas

Say I have a vector x, and a (short) list of values v to match against. I want to find which elements of x are present in v. For example, if

```
x = {10 11 12 13 12 13 14 15};
v = {12 13};
```

I want to obtain the vector `{3 4 5 6}`, these being the elements of x whose values are either 12 or 13. Is there a simple way to do this, without having to do an explicit loop over all the elements of v?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are in PROC IML.
Use the XSECT function to find the intersection of the two sets:

```
z = xsect(x,v);
```

(and if you want the difference, use SETDIF).

BTW, there is a discussion forum dedicated to soley SAS/IML questions:
http://support.sas.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=47